# Sencha touch 2 charts: draw line on specific range

Tags: charts, sencha-touch-2

Is it possible to display certain series for line charts on the given range? E.g. I have two lines, orange occupies all plot (and x-axis are bases on its values), but I'd like a green one to end on "12" value.

[image]

I tried removing data from the green line, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Hacky solution is like that :

Change the color of the line to grey(the same as background color) once some condition is fullfilled.
In the below example I assume that background color is #eeeeee.

First create some singleton util:

```
Ext.define('Company.util.Factory', {
  singleton: true,
   generateChartLineSerieRenderer:function(input, color){
      var result = function (sprite, config, rendererData, index) {return {}};

      // color should be the same as color of your chart's background
      color = color || 'white';

      // check if input is defined, if not then it should use default configuration
      input = input || {
                          field       :'x',
                          action      :'lt',
                          actionValue : 12 
                        }

      switch(input.action){
        case "lt":
          result =  function (sprite, config, rendererData, index) {
            if(rendererData.store.getData().items[index].data[input.field] < input.actionValue){
              return { strokeStyle: color };
            }
          }
          break;

        case "gt":
          result =  function (sprite, config, rendererData, index) {
            if(rendererData.store.getData().items[index].data[input.field] > input.actionValue){
              return { strokeStyle: color };
            }
          }
          break;
      }
    }

    return result;
});
```

Above function Factory.generateChartLineSerieRenderer will return function which will change color of the line if some condition will be fulfilled.

You can use it like this:

```
series: [
    {
        type: 'line',
        title: "Line Orange",
        xField: "x",
        yField: "y1",
        style: {
            stroke: "orange"
        },
    },
    {
        type: 'line',
        title: "Line green",
        xField: "x",
        yField: "y2",
        style: {
            stroke: "green"
        },
        renderer: Company.util.Factory.generateChartLineSerieRenderer(
                      {
                          field       :'x',
                          action      :'gt',
                          actionValue : 12 
                      },
                      "#eeeeee"
                  )
    }
],
```